# Importing neighboring package in Java

Tags: java, import, package

I have file `/project/src/config/configInterface.java`.

In neighboring directory (`/project/src/anotherfolder/hereItryToUse.java`) I can't use `configInterface` class, because I don't know how to import this package.

How I can do it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We encourage you to [research your questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). If you've [tried something already](http://whathaveyoutried.com/), please add it to the question - if not, research and attempt your question first, and then come back.

Comment: How do you use your compiler? Via command line? Do you pass all files as argument? Also have a look at naming conventions, your classes start with a lower case letter (or is this only an example?). Also you seem to be mixing up “package” and “class” - which one do you mean?

Comment: Example only. I use geany editor and compile there.
When I import packages from sub-directories, all is ok. 
Simply i don't know how to import packages from neighboring directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what IDE do you use?

ctrl(cmd)+shift+o is the shortcut for importing packages in Eclipse (don't know for others), but you can definitely use the package